# SQL Replace column values using wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL table as below containing special characters:

[image]

I want to replace them with letters 'ec' so the text will be 'Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 1' ect.

I have done code like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Name = REPLACE(Name,'zdj��','zdjec')
WHERE Name LIKE 'Dodatek na podstawie zdj%'
```

but it is not seeing �� marks. For example when I do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE Name LIKE '%��%'
```

it returns 0 rows.

I want to do something like

```
SET Name = REPLACE(Name,'zdj[][]','zdjec')
```

but SQL seems to not accept wildcards.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Probably a display problem. Unprintable characters show up like those.

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a display issue. Try the following code to demostrate whether this is the case:

```
declare @Name nvarchar(100)
set @Name = 'Dodatek na podstawie zdj�� 1'

select @Name as 'Without substitution', replace(@Name, '��', 'ec') as 'With substitution'
```

Returns:

```
Without substitution:   Dodatek na podstawie zdj?? 1
With substitution:      Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](@S varchar(max), @t varchar(100))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    ;with  cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(C) As (Select Top (32) Char(Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1) From cte1 a,cte1 b)
    SELECT @S = Replace(@S,C,@t)
    FROM cte2

    Return ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(@S,' ','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡',' ')))
End


UPDATE table_name
SET Name = [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](Name,'ec')
WHERE Name LIKE 'Dodatek na podstawie zdj%'
```

Comment: Huh... that function looks familiar.   Attribution would be the polite thing to do.

Comment: And set-based tally table code notwithstanding: this is a scalar UDF which returns varchar(max). If performance is important then this is NOT the solution for you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for `PATINDEX` and `STUFF`.

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (SomeName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT  @table (SomeName)
SELECT     CONCAT('Dodatek na podstawie zdj',special.chr,f.N)
FROM       (VALUES('§§ '),('ŒŒ '))     AS special(chr)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) AS f(N)

-- Solution
SELECT 
  OldValue = t.SomeName,
  NewValue = STUFF(t.SomeName, PATINDEX('%[^0-9a-zA-Z][^0-9a-zA-Z]%',t.SomeName), 2, 'ec')
FROM @table AS t;
```

**Returns:**

```
OldValue                        NewValue
------------------------------- -------------------------------
Dodatek na podstawie zdj§§ 1    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 1
Dodatek na podstawie zdj§§ 2    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 2
Dodatek na podstawie zdj§§ 3    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 3
Dodatek na podstawie zdj§§ 4    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 4
Dodatek na podstawie zdj§§ 5    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 5
Dodatek na podstawie zdjŒŒ 1    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 1
Dodatek na podstawie zdjŒŒ 2    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 2
Dodatek na podstawie zdjŒŒ 3    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 3
Dodatek na podstawie zdjŒŒ 4    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 4
Dodatek na podstawie zdjŒŒ 5    Dodatek na podstawie zdjec 5
```